# Norms of eigenvalues bigger than 1 implies $|Ax|>x$ for all nonzero $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math, normed-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If all the eigenvalues of $A$ (an n by n real matrix) have norms bigger than 1, is it true that $|Ax|>|x|$ for all nonzero $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$? (This is clearly true if $x$ is an eigenvector corresponding to a real eigenvalue). Please explain.

This question arises from Problem 1:

http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2013/IMC2013-day1-solutions.pdf

Comment: Also please prove it for symmetric $A$.

Answer (score 3):

What you are saying is generally not true. For example, consider the matrix: $$ \left( \begin{matrix}
  1.1 & 1.1 \\
  0 & 1.1
 \end{matrix} \right) $$ You can check that the vector $$ \left( 1 , -1 \right) $$ gets shortened.

It is not the same question as Problem 1 in the contest, because there they specify that A and B are symmetric, which implies they are diagonalizable.

Comment: Thank you. How would you prove it if we assume $A$ is symmetric?

Answer (score 1):

For Symmetric Matrices: Try to learn about Rayleigh-Ritz ratio for symmetric matrices. What ever you are trying to prove follows from the fact that 
\begin{align}
1\leq \lambda_{min}^2 =\min_{\mathbf{x}\neq 0}\frac{\mathbf{x^HA^HAx}}{\mathbf{x^Hx}}
\end{align}